# Glide - Round image without circle crop

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide

I'm using this code to show profile image:

```
  Glide.with(getContext()).load(url)
                                .dontAnimate()
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                                 .circleCrop()
                                .into(my_profile_image);
```

But circleCrop() is cropping the image too much. So is there another way to round an image without too much cropping? I research it but I couldn't find another method.

Answer (score 2):

```
Glide.with(getContext()).load(url)
                            .dontAnimate()
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                             .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(new RoundedCorners(10))) // round
                            .into(my_profile_image);
```

Comment: This rounds corners but now the image is like a rectangle. I changed the value 80,120 etc. but it still like a rectangle not circle.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
Glide.with(getContext()).load(url)
      .dontAnimate()
      .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
      .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
      .into(my_profile_image);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but nothing has changed. Still the image is cropped to much. Is there another way?